# How can I exclude an index of an array from being looped in a forLoop() after it has been used once?

Tags: javascript

Currently, I am creating a random group generator. Right now, I have a for loop that creates a div and inserts it into a larger (parent?) div. In these smaller divs, I am using a random number to create a random index that is used to display random names.

**Problem**: However, I do not know how to make it so that after one index is chosen, it cannot be used again.

**Question**: How can I make a for loop that excludes a number after it is used once?

```js
const inputArticle = document.querySelector('#input-article');
const inputForm = document.querySelector('#input-form');
const table = document.querySelector('#table');
const groupOptions = document.querySelector('select[ name="group-options" ]');
const createTeamsButton = document.querySelector('#create-teams-button');
const outputArticle = document.querySelector('#output-article');
const outputMainDiv = document.querySelector('#output-main-div');

let peopleArray = [];
let numberPeople = 0;
let rowNumber = 0;
let groupNumber = 1;
let maxPeopleInGroup = 0;
let maxNumberGroups = 0;

function addRow(person) {
    let row = table.tBodies[0].insertRow(-1);
    let cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    let cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    let cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    let removeButton = document.createElement("button");

    cell1.style.width = "5vmin";
    cell1.style.height = "5vmin";
    cell1.style.fontSize = "18pt";
    cell1.style.fontWeight = "300";

    cell2.style.width = "5vmin";
    cell2.style.height = "5vmin";
    cell2.style.fontSize = "18pt";
    cell2.style.fontWeight = "300";

    cell3.style.width = "5vmin";
    cell3.style.height = "5vmin";
    cell3.style.fontSize = "18pt";
    cell3.style.fontWeight = "300";
    
    removeButton.dataset = person;
    removeButton.innerText = `Remove ${person.firstName} ${person.lastName}`;
    removeButton.setAttribute("type", "button");

    removeButton.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        peopleArray = peopleArray.filter(p => p != person);
        row.remove();
    })

    cell1.innerText = person.firstName;
    cell2.innerText = person.lastName;
    cell3.appendChild(removeButton);
}

function createNames(event) {
    let person = {
        firstName:  document.getElementById(`firstName`).value,
        lastName: document.getElementById(`lastName`).value
    }

    event.target.reset();
    addRow(person);
    peopleArray.push(person);
    numberPeople++;
    //alert(JSON.stringify(peopleArray));
}

function submit() {
    if (groupOptions.value != "") {
        inputArticle.classList.add("hidden");
        outputArticle.classList.remove("hidden");
        createGroups();
    }
}

function createGroups() {
    maxPeopleInGroup = groupOptions.value;
    maxNumberGroups = Math.floor(maxPeopleInGroup / peopleArray.length);
    let divWidth = 5 * maxPeopleInGroup;
    let divHeight = 7.5 * maxPeopleInGroup;

    while (numberPeople / maxPeopleInGroup > maxNumberGroups) {
        maxNumberGroups++;
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < maxNumberGroups; i++) {
        let div = document.createElement("div");
        div.setAttribute("id", `group${groupNumber}`);
        div.style.width = `${divWidth}vw`;
        div.style.height = `${divHeight}vh`;
        div.style.textAlign = "center";
        div.style.alignItems = "center";
        div.style.fontFamily = "Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif";
        div.style.fontSize = "18pt";
        div.style.fontWeight = "400";
        div.style.border = "1px solid black";
        outputMainDiv.appendChild(div);
        div.innerHTML = `Group ${groupNumber}:</br>`;

        for (let k = 0; k < maxPeopleInGroup; k++) {
            let index = Math.round(Math.random() * peopleArray.length);
            div.innerHTML += `${peopleArray[index].firstName} ${peopleArray[index].lastName} </br>`;
        }

        groupNumber++;
    }
}     

inputArticle.classList.remove("hidden");
outputArticle.classList.add("hidden");

window.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
    if (event.key == 'Enter') {
        if (firstName.value && lastName.value) {
            createNames(event);
        }    
    }
}, false)

inputForm.addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
   createNames(event);
   event.target.reset();
})

createTeamsButton.addEventListener('click', submit);
```

```css
#input-article.hidden {
    display: none;
}

table {
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

th {
    width: 50vmin;
    height: 10vmin;
    font-size: 20pt;
    font-weight: 800;
}

input {
    width: 50vmin;
    height: 5vmin;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 18pt;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#group {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#output-article.hidden {
    display: none;
}

#output-main-div {
    width: 95vw; /*Percentage width of browser*/ 
    height: 95vh; /*Percentage height of browser*/
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#input-article p, #input-article option {
    font-size: 18pt;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE-edge">
        <meta name="viewport", content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>

    <body>
        <article id="input-article">
            <form method="dialog" id="input-form">
                <table id="table" border="1">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>First Name:</th>
                            <th>Last Name:</th>
                            <th>Actions</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    
                    <tbody></tbody>

                    <tfoot>
                        <tr>
                            <td><input name="first-name" type="text" required placeholder="First Name" id="firstName"></td>
                            <td><input name="last-name" type="text" required placeholder="Last Name" id="lastName"></td>
                            <td>
                                <button type="submit">Add Person</button>
                                <button type="reset">Clear Names</button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tfoot>
                </table> 
            </form><br>

            <div id="group">
                <p>Number of people per group:&nbsp;</p>
                <select name = "group-options" required>
                    <option value="">--Select Answer--</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                    <option value="6">6</option>
                    <option value="7">7</option>
                    <option value="8">8</option>
                    <option value="9">9</option>
                    <option value="10">10</option>
                    <option value="11">11</option>
                    <option value="12">12</option>
                </select>
            </div>    

            <div id="buttons">
                <button id="create-teams-button">Randomize Teams</button>
            </div>
        </article>

        <article id="output-article">
            <div id="output-main-div"></div>
        </article>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: [Shuffle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array) the array and then read n elements from the top.

Answer (score 0):

Keep moving your already chosen elements to the start of the list, and then pick from the remaining elements in the array.

```
    for (let k = 0; k < maxPeopleInGroup; k++) {
        // subtract k from the random possibilities and then add after to ignore previously 
        let index = Math.round(Math.random() * (peopleArray.length - k)) + k; chosen elements)
        div.innerHTML += `${peopleArray[index].firstName} ${peopleArray[index].lastName} </br>`;
        //swap array elements
        let temp = peopleArray[k];
        peopleArray[k] = peopleArray[index];
        peopleArray[index] = temp;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just change the order of the `people` array and then use it to loop over each item in sequential order.

The following function takes an array as input and returns it with the items in random order:

```js
function shuffle(array) {
  for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    [array[i], array[j]] = [array[j], array[i]];
  }
  return array;
}
```

On each iteration, `j` is always assigned to a number within the range determined by the current value of `i`. Finally, `array[i]` is being swapped with `array[j]` using [destructuring assignment syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

You can use it as follows:

```js
const people = [
  {first: "john", last: "doe"},
  {first: "jane", last: "doe"},
  {first: "jack", last: "doe"},
];

shuffle(people).forEach(person => {
  console.log(person.first, person.last);
});

// Example output: jane doe, jack doe, john doe
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually ran into this problem myself today and opted to go with using the Web Crypto API rather than keeping track of id duplicates.

```
const id = self.crypto.randomUUID();
```

[Crypto - Web APIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Crypto)